# MongoDB log file shows connection accepted & end connection constantly

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine, redhat

I'm trying to install `MongoDb` server in `Redhat 7` `GCE` 
After starting Mongod process with replication, the mongolog shows an error log..

```
`2017-12-29T20:51:12.853+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted 
 from 10.142.0.2:38130 #53 (1 connection now open)
 2017-12-29T20:51:42.861+0530 I NETWORK  [conn53] end connection 
 10.142.0.2:38130 (0 connections now open)
 2017-12-29T20:51:42.862+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted 
 from 10.142.0.2:38136 #54 (1 connection now open)
 2017-12-29T20:52:12.868+0530 I NETWORK  [conn54] end connection 
 10.142.0.2:38136 (0 connections now open)
 2017-12-29T20:52:12.869+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted 
 from 10.142.0.2:38144 #55 (1 connection now open)
 2017-12-29T20:52:42.877+0530 I NETWORK  [conn55] end connection 
 10.142.0.2:38144 (0 connections now open)
 2017-12-29T20:52:42.877+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted 
 from 10.142.0.2:38150 #56 (1 connection now open)
 2017-12-29T20:53:12.883+0530 I NETWORK  [conn56] end connection 
 10.142.0.2:38150 (0 connections now open)
 2017-12-29T20:53:12.883+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted 
 from 10.142.0.2:38156 #57 (1 connection now open)
 2017-12-29T20:53:42.891+0530 I NETWORK  [conn57] end connection 
 10.142.0.2:38156 (0 connections now open)
 2017-12-29T20:53:42.892+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted 
 from 10.142.0.2:38162 #58 (1 connection now open)
 2017-12-29T20:54:12.900+0530 I NETWORK  [conn58] end connection 
 10.142.0.2:38162 (0 connections now open)
 2017-12-29T20:54:12.900+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted 
 from 10.142.0.2:38170 #59 (1 connection now open)
 2017-12-29T20:54:42.908+0530 I NETWORK  [conn59] end connection 
 10.142.0.2:38170 (0 connections now open)
 2017-12-29T20:54:42.908+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted 
 from 10.142.0.2:38174 #60 (1 connection now open)
 2017-12-29T20:55:12.917+0530 I NETWORK  [conn60] end connection 
 10.142.0.2:38174 (0 connections now open)
```

`

I can connect from the redhat shell as

> mongo --port 34672

but when i try to connect from an external ip it fails.

i was not able to find the reason for this error after checking all the error logs and searching in the web.

Answer (score 1):

These log entries to not indicate an error. It is simply reporting connections. As for the reason for the connections, there could be several:

1. If you have an application using MongoDB, these connections are likely coming from that application.
2. If you have monitoring such as Stackdriver Monitoring installed, these could be connections from the monitoring to fetch statistics from MongoDB.
3. If you are using a cluster of MongoDB servers, this could be connections or health-checking between them.

I think (2) or (3) are especially likely, given that they are coming from internal IP addresses are are spaced exactly 30 seconds apart.

I believe your issue connecting externally is unrelated to these messages. If that is what you are really concerned about, I suggest you open a new question about that.

Comment: I have noticed this error lines when i am not able to connect connect the mongodb server with remote app `MongoChef` (timeout). The try constantly shows `end connection` error line with the remote machine ip. Also using replicated nodes as well.